# Random Out Of Bounds after removing item from static list used by multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, listadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a fragment with a `viewpager` with adapter extending `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` with three slidable fragments inside. the main fragment has a `static` list of data, and three sub-fragments references and show the same list (don't ask why). The list item can be removed by a button inside the row layout or by clicking clear-all button after the list in each of those three fragments.

My problem is that after removing one or all the items with the buttons, sometimes i get an instant `index out of bounds exception` (no application code in stack trace, to find where the exception is coming from) or randomly sometimes removal work, but fragments nearby display old data with the extra item, and clicking to remove it ofcourse throws `out of bounds exception`, because after some debugging I can see that size of list passed to adapter to recreate the nearby fragment is lower by one (removal is successful) so I believe the list is not notified/invalidated correctly. Any help, since stacktrace can't help?

Btw I'm using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE` to recreate the fragments with new data on each swipe, `notifyDataSetChanged` to notify the adapter of changed data, and `invalidate()` the listview in `onViewCreated()`, but they don't help.

relevant code:

**Main Fragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends BaseFragment<CategoryTreeItem> {

public static List<Map.Entry<EventTreeItem, String>> betList = new ArrayList<>();
...
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

    SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    }    
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<String> items;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.three_categories);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FirstFragment();
                return fragment;

            case 1:
                fragment = new SecondFragment();
                return fragment;

            case 2:
                fragment = new ThirdFragment();
                return fragment;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return FragmentStatePagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

**Three fragments** (they are needed since the layout and functionality is a bit different)

```
public class First/Second/ThirdFragment extends BaseListFragment<ArrayList<EventTreeItem>> {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_first/second/thirdfragment, MainFragment.betList);
    getListView().setItemsCanFocus(true);
    View footerView = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.include_first/second/third_footer, getListView(), false);
    getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().invalidate();
    //handles REMOVE ALL button for all fragments footer button
    Helper.setUpClearOption(footerView, adapter);

    }
}
```

**MyListAdapter**

```
@CompileStatic 
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Map.Entry<EventTreeItem,String>> {

private int mResourceId;
private List<Map.Entry<EventTreeItem,String>> mObjects;

public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Map.Entry<EventTreeItem,String>> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mResourceId = resource;
    mObjects = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mResourceId, parent, false);
    }

    //------setting a lot of text for textViews
    // .....
    //------

    ImageView ivRemove = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivRemove);
    ivRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Tried removing directly from adapter, not helping
            //                MyListAdapter.this.remove(mObjects.get(position));
            MainFragment.betList.remove(position);
            MyListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    return view;
    }
}
```

**Remove All helper method** (also returning instant `OOB` or not notifying neighbor fragments)

```
public static void setUpClearOption(View view, final ArrayAdapter adapter) {
    ImageView ivRemoveAll = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivRemoveAll);
    ivRemoveAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

So any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix My problem by creating three listadapters for each of my fragments (static adapters instantiaiting with `null` value ) and in `onClick` I check each of those three adapters if they are not `null` (since adapters are `null` until after `onViewCreated`, and it is called only when the current fragment is a neighbor). All three adapters use the same data.